# Adding an Image Style

Tags: media

I'm new to Drupal, and I'm attempting to add an image style to a Basic Page in the "Manage Displays" area. After savings, there is no effect with the images on my basic pages (i.e. the image style was not applied) What would cause this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks! (PS - I'm sure this is probably a novice question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are maybe looking at the Default display (top right corner of page). Make sure you are on the Full Content, or Teaser (as the case may be) to make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Thank Geoff! That worked well. Does the same go for adding image styles to Views as well? I ran into the same issue there.

Comment: For views, you can adjust the image style in the setup for the field itself. I don't know of a way to adjust it if you dont include it as a field - but as a field you can choose which style and a bunch of other options.

Answer (score 0):

I think (if i did understand you correctly) you need to add a new image style first and then you apply it to your image in the manage display area.

you can add a new style by going to admin/config/media/image-styles and then click on "Add Style"